# Magento 2 - Custom Registration Form For Guest user in custom phtml file

Tags: module, customer-registration

How to build a custom registration form that can be shown in custom phtml file and visible only for guest customer. In the form also show user a checkbox field (mandatory) to confirm account creation and create account after submission.

Comment: registrations forms are by default show to unregistered (not logged in) "guests"

Comment: Want to display form on custom page in custom module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps to achieve according to your requirement.

In your custom module , please write below code in any of your custom xml file.

> Step 1: Please write below code in xml file
> PackageName/Vendor/view/frontend/layout/custom_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="login.register.section" template="PackageName_Vendor::custom.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="newregister" template="PackageName_Vendor::form/newregister.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="attribute_data" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Block\DataProviders\AddressAttributeData</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                    <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="registerSubmitButton" xsi:type="string">.action.submit</item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Step 2: Please create file custom.phtml file under path
> PackageName/Vendor/view/frontend/templates

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session'); 
$request = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http'); ?>

<?php if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()): ?>
    <div class="login-container">
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('newregister'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> Step 3: Please create file newregister.phtml under path
> PackageName/Vendor/view/frontend/templates/form/

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate
// phpcs:disable Generic.Files.LineLength.TooLong

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register $block */
?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('form_fields_before') ?>
<?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.extra') ?>
<form class="form create account form-create-account" action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPostActionUrl()) ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset create info">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Personal Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSuccessUrl()) ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getErrorUrl()) ?>">
        <?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name::class)->setObject($block->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($block->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
            <div class="field choice newsletter">
                <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if ($block->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox">
                <label for="is_subscribed" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?></span></label>
            </div>
            <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter') ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob::class) ?>
        <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_dob->setDate($block->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_taxvat = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat::class) ?>
        <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_taxvat->setTaxvat($block->getFormData()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_gender = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Gender::class) ?>
        <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_gender->setGender($block->getFormData()->getGender())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
        <fieldset class="fieldset address">
            <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1" />

            <?php $_company = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Company::class) ?>
            <?php if ($_company->isEnabled()): ?>
                <?= $_company->setCompany($block->getFormData()->getCompany())->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php $_telephone = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Telephone::class) ?>
            <?php if ($_telephone->isEnabled()): ?>
                <?= $_telephone->setTelephone($block->getFormData()->getTelephone())->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php $_fax = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Fax::class) ?>
            <?php if ($_fax->isEnabled()): ?>
                <?= $_fax->setFax($block->getFormData()->getFax())->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper(\Magento\Customer\Helper\Address::class)->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
            <div class="field street required">
                <label for="street_1" class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('street') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getStreet(0)) ?>" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('street') ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClass) ?>">
                    <div class="nested">
                        <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                        <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper(\Magento\Customer\Helper\Address::class)->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                            <div class="field additional">
                                <label class="label" for="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i ?>">
                                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address')) ?></span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="control">
                                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getStreetLine($_i - 1)) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Street Address %1', $_i)) ?>" id="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClass) ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field required">
                <label for="city" class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('city') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="city" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('city') ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Customer\Helper\Address::class)->getAttributeValidationClass('city')) ?>" id="city">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field region required">
                <label for="region_id" class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('region') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('region') ?>" class="validate-select region_id" style="display:none;">
                        <option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please select a region, state or province.')) ?></option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('region') ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Customer\Helper\Address::class)->getAttributeValidationClass('region')) ?>" style="display:none;">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field zip required">
                <label for="zip" class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('postcode') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('postcode') ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Customer\Helper\Address::class)->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode')) ?>">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field country required">
                <label for="country" class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('country_id') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <?= $block->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $addressAttributes = $block->getChildBlock('customer_form_address_user_attributes');?>
            <?php if ($addressAttributes): ?>
                <?php $addressAttributes->setEntityType('customer_address'); ?>
                <?php $addressAttributes->setFieldIdFormat('address:%1$s')->setFieldNameFormat('address[%1$s]');?>
                <?php $block->restoreSessionData($addressAttributes->getMetadataForm(), 'address');?>
                <?= $addressAttributes->setShowContainer(false)->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif;?>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1">
        </fieldset>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign-in Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
        <div class="field required">
            <label for="email_address" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" id="email_address" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" class="input-text" data-mage-init='{"mage/trim-input":{}}' data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field password required">
            <label for="password" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Password')) ?>"
                       class="input-text"
                       data-password-min-length="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getMinimumPasswordLength()) ?>"
                       data-password-min-character-sets="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getRequiredCharacterClassesNumber()) ?>"
                       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
                       autocomplete="off">
                <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" aria-live="polite">
                    <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password Strength')) ?>:
                        <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No Password')) ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="field confirmation required">
            <label for="password-confirmation" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Confirm Password')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Confirm Password')) ?>" id="password-confirmation" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, equalTo:'#password'}" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field choice confirm_account required">
            <input type="checkbox" name="confirm_account" id="confirm_account" class="checkbox" data-validate="{required:true}">
            <label for="confirm_account" class="label">
                <span><?= __('Confirm account creation') ?></span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info') ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Create an Account')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Create an Account')) ?></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action back" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Back')) ?></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function($){

    var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
    var ignore = <?= /* @noEscape */ $_dob->isEnabled() ? '\'input[id$="full"]\'' : 'null' ?>;

    dataForm.mage('validation', {
    <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.prop('id').search('full') !== -1) {
                var dobElement = $(element).parents('.customer-dob'),
                    errorClass = error.prop('class');
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                dobElement.find('.validate-custom').addClass(errorClass)
                    .after('<div class="' + errorClass + '"></div>');
            }
            else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        ignore: ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')'
    <?php else: ?>
        ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
    <?php endif ?>
    }).find('input:text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
});
</script>
<?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#country": {
            "regionUpdater": {
                "optionalRegionAllowed": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getConfig('general/region/display_all') ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
                "regionListId": "#region_id",
                "regionInputId": "#region",
                "postcodeId": "#zip",
                "form": "#form-validate",
                "regionJson": <?= /* @noEscape */ $this->helper(\Magento\Directory\Helper\Data::class)->getRegionJson() ?>,
                "defaultRegion": "<?= (int) $block->getFormData()->getRegionId() ?>",
                "countriesWithOptionalZip": <?= /* @noEscape */ $this->helper(\Magento\Directory\Helper\Data::class)->getCountriesWithOptionalZip(true) ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        ".field.password": {
            "passwordStrengthIndicator": {
                "formSelector": "form.form-create-account"
            }
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Customer/js/block-submit-on-send": {
                "formId": "form-validate"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Note:** I have shown checkbox field (mandatory) to confirm account creation in custom registration form , please do whatever you want to do on this checkbox according to your requirement. Also this form will create account after submission.

Please check and let me know if you have any query.

Thanks
Cheers!

Comment: I want to add password field and save this is my question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332288/magento-2-add-registration-form-fields-in-custom-from-and-create-customer-acco

Comment: This link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332288/magento-2-add-registration-form-fields-in-custom-from-and-create-customer-acco shows 404